# Trying to run a simple web server to receive post data from my utility company that uses greenbuttondata

Tags: python, http, sockets

I have this running in a simple python script that runs a http server, its supposed to retrieve data from a post call from my utility company, ive noticed though that as soon as i run it, and navigate to https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ and check if my port is open for 443, it says closed (even though its open before)

i put this in a test.py and run it so i can wait for the post request and download the xml data, but for whatever it turns off my port when i go and check it

```
 from pgesmd_self_access.api import SelfAccessApi
from pgesmd_self_access.server import SelfAccessServer
from pgesmd_self_access.helpers import save_espi_xml
pge_api = SelfAccessApi.auth( < i changed this to reflect my auth file > )
SelfAccessServer(pge_api, save_file=save_espi_xml)
```

i thought the port should stay open on my router? it doesnt seem like normal behavior

i think i need to implement SO_REUSEADDR in his code according to some docket documentation, but im not sure how to do that

```
class SelfAccessServer:
    """Server class for PGE SMD Self Access API."""

    def __init__(
        self, api_instance, save_file=None, filename=None, to_db=True, close_after=False
    ):
        """Initialize and start the server on construction."""
        PgePostHandler.api = api_instance
        PgePostHandler.save_file = save_file
        PgePostHandler.filename = filename
        PgePostHandler.to_db = to_db
        server = HTTPServer(("", 7999), PgePostHandler)

        server.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(
            server.socket,
            certfile=api_instance.cert[0],
            keyfile=api_instance.cert[1],
            server_side=True,
        )

        if close_after:
            server.handle_request()
        else:
            server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Were you running in your local system? most home wifi won't have public ip and you need to ask for static ip.

Comment: you are probably behind nat gateway (shared public ip)

Comment: IP address hasn’t changed in over a year  as soon as I run the script my port turns off it’s a python issue nothing else